# Given a sequence of numbers, print out all possible sets such that the sum is less than a number

Tags: code-golf, number

The problem has 3 inputs.

**L**: a list of all numbers

**size**: the size each set can be

**max**: the max sum amongst each set

The challenge is as follows:

Given L, size and max, construct as many sets from L such that the number of elements is **size** and the sum of each of the elements does not exceed **max**.

Examples:

```
func(L=[1,2,3,4], size=2, max=5) = [{1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,4}]
```

Notice how each of the values in the outputted set are sum <= max.

```
func(L=[1,2,3,4], size=3, max=6) = [{1,2,3}]

func(L=[1,2,3,4], size=3, max=5) = [{}] or empty list, whichever you want
```

Note that in the set you cannot have duplicated items. `ie: {2,1} = {1,2}`

Constraints on inputs:

**L**: 0 or more elements

**size**: 0 <= size <= len(L)

**max**: 0 or more

If a list has 0 items, then always return the empty set.

If the size is 0, then always return the empty set.

If max is 0, it is possible that there are negative values in **L**, in which case the returned sets need not be empty.

Shorted bytes wins!

Comment: I would suggest guaranteeing that `L` will be non-empty. It is generally advisable to avoid edge cases in code-golf challenges, as they don't add much and can cost many bytes.

Comment: This could really use some more test cases, especially test cases where the elements in **L** are not all unique.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
.ÆêʒO@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f73Db4VWnJvk7/P9vxBVtqGOoYwSExkBoomMSy2VkAAA)

Comment: Duplicated items in list: try this: `2,[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],20`. [1,2] is repeated

Comment: @KSplitX Thanks, fixed. It would be helpful if you added that test case to the question!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>82</s> 79 bytes

```python
lambda l,s,m:[i for i in __import__("itertools").combinations(l,s)if sum(i)<=m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBCsIwEEDRvacYuspAEGrUhdiT1BJSNTiQyYRkXHj62L24@vDgl4@@JLsep1tPgddHgGSb5ctMEKUCAWXwnrhIVe/NQPqsKpLagPu78Eo5KEluZtuQIrQ3G8LrxEsvlbKaaObRHqyzx2XLCXH36@6vnxH7Fw)

-3 bytes thanks to squid

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
≥ᵗ⟨⟨⊇l⟩+⟩
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/486lz7cOv3R/BUg1NWe82j@Sm0g/v8/WiE6OtpQx0jHWMckVscoVsc0VgdZxDhWxwxDxDRWIRYA)

Takes input as `[[L,size],max]` through the input variable and [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/10753#10753) the output through the output variable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
àV â fÈx §W
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4FYg4iBmyHggp1c&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNF0KMgo1Ci1S)

```
àV â fÈx §W     :Implicit input of array U=L and integers V=size & W=max
àV              :Combinations of U of length V
   â            :Deduplicate
     f          :Filter by
      È         :Function
       x        :  Sum
         §W     :  Less than or equal to W
```

Comment: Not unique outputs. Try the following: 
`[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],4,20`... `1,1,2,3` for example is repeated

Comment: @KSplitX, Missed that. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 56 bytes

```r
function(L,s,m,a=combn(L,s))unique(a[,colSums(a)<=m],,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0/DR6dYJ1cn0TY5PzcJzNPULM3LLCxN1UiM1knOzwkuzS3WSNS0sc2N1dEx0vyfpmFoZaKjYKSjYKrJBeUY6yiYIXPAMkWpBVClmmDlRgaa/wE)

Creates a matrix where each column is a subset of `L` of size `s`, and keeps those for which the sum is less than `m`. Output is a matrix, with each column corresponding to one allowable subset (if there is only one such subset, the output is a `s×1` matrix and R will display it on one row instead by default).

Note that this fails for the edge case where `L` is empty. Handling that edge case as specified in the challenge takes 19 more bytes:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 75 bytes

```r
function(L,s,m,a=combn(L,s))`if`(length(L),unique(a[,colSums(a)<=m],,2),{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcq9DsIgGIXh3atg/L7kDII/g5E76OZoTIoElKRAbctkvHaMpIPjc847Va@rL8kuISfqMCPCaJvjvYm5D76nwaXH8qSOUVJ4FUfmCpuHS4kzGT7reAMU4/3h6kme9hAK4sCbFTuI4z/aM7lxTbnlavtbLTEkJNcv)

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0/DR6dYJ1cn0TY5PzcpT6M0L7OwNFXDR1OnWFMzMVonOT8nuDS3WCNR08Y2N/Z/moahlYmOgpGOgqkmF5RjrKNghswByxSlFkCVaoKVGxlo/gcA)? I don't think I've ever noticed that `unique` has a `margin` argument, that's quite a helpful tip! I usually just `unique(t())`; the comments on other answers seem to indicate that `[1,1]` shouldn't be a valid output on `[1,1,2,3],2,20`

Comment: @Giuseppe I discovered the `margin` argument today as well. I was going to `unique(t())` but checked the help of `unique` just in case... and luckily, the argument exists! I guess we need to wait for OP to clarify the challenge to know where to apply `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

```
Σ⊂
euK↑⁇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9ziR11NXKml3o/aJj5qbP//P9pQwUjBWMEklsuYyxQA)

Takes input as `list`, `size`, `max sum` on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
QœcS>¥Ðḟ⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//UcWTY1M@wqXDkOG4n@KBtf///1sxLDIsMyw0Xf8y/zU)

Comment: [You need to move the `Q` to the beginning.](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//xZNjUz7CpcOQ4bif4oG1Uf///1sxLDIsMyw0LDFd/zL/NQ) The challenge doesn't really have adequate test cases right now, so you might easily miss that.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
{SMfgeQsT.PhQht
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzrYNy09NbA4RC8gIzCj5P//aEMdIx1jHZNYIGEKAA)

```
{SMfgeQsT.PhQhtQ  # (last Q implicit; Q = input)
         .P       # all permutations
           hQ     #   of Q[0]
             htQ  #           of length Q[1:][0] = Q[1]
   f              # filter those with lambda T:
     eQ           #   Q[-1]
    g             #          >=
       sT         #             sum(T)
 SM               # sort each element
{                 # deduplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 286 bytes

```
fun p(l:List<Int>,s:Int,m:Int){val r=MutableList(0){""}
val a=l.toSet().toList()
fun r(n:Int,b:Int,t:Int,u:List<Int>){if(n<1){if(t<=m)r.add(u.joinToString(",","{","}"))}else
for(e in b..a.size-1)r(n-1,e+1,t+a[e],u+listOf(a[e]))}
r(s,0,0,List(0){0})
println(r.joinToString(",","[","]"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVhdb9vGEn33rxgTAUohLC3ZSdAKVoH0414EcJqizpvhh7W0ktiSXHV3acU19NvTM7O7JFWnMFrboChydr7OmZld/258XbWfz87oXbvr/Jxa47dVu6G1seS3mlZ6rbrak9fO01I57U4gzC/3hrBUOzJrcju11OT0TlnlNVWt1xttXcmyH6FlXVksZ3GqnOitKzzwhnbWLLUbJJ1emnYVRN3WdPWKtupei7m2a@6gdc6yXmQ9uepPTQor@EGjPlVN15DrGlH4Y7erqyU8csHevao73CsLNzatsXpVnrDcD1ZDaBWDhodLs9K0MfWalltV17rdaLG69X7n5mdn/J5fl86r5e/6E6QgUi5Nc/bH2ezbi/NXr1n8/9W9bknB0T863SJDSFUMokDkSBOZzhMssPTOOFfd1RKXQwzLLZxRPoSKqOBXjVSF6BXrDbroJCUPycT6BhlzdAEUgGjI7NUc0pICeABzyQt@xxmcByOcS61glzO7hIk7zRJI6zzlVzxRjWk3UJZkk/0@WewrfFibujb7AFjIxVUxIAZtBTLdOm@7pWf5RrUP4hInYG1NQ1d/y0OMGFFoBKpbLyHA2hEP2EcWYffwyY/G4isDEoDoBOC0FkckSz99Us0OKRZ/1127zK8WN7PivLgoXt0GxxfnBYsvXk9oQTePeHkoWBp3F4eCHs/Dx6x4dbglfvGz8RWA35r9kTuRiVXL36SiOg@0mISce2YoB3G56J37B38ugj9ven/gwO3z8tF/OGksS@tm5x@EIQXtt9Vyq@@R5gfT0V6BpTESHYAIXoujLAGicDK5TCW7qehWVHnduJIq8AuZmR1gU1ImNSfAK9QAOkgbyTqPZJ1yh2lQoEe4BaZOOSsCNz7Btvxq0pO0X8dP3q0T6bkepsGbgl1H7dR79eDIat/ZNvWTkASEVVJc31cFGDb90tIE37A0ruRSCYsqzzd9cScqIzYV/Gz1RnlUx4gUKBNcBQhpuslMMBpIAgozeTn1d9F3MX69NZaTf/fAfW9fte70JLB7h/rgLgdm@Ao531ce6k0jCR4148BHO5RzSb@gsTfao2UIN/mtkCVWqySpSFU99GCYSkpzlp/TFa6X71r/XRHhxH1xQvgRAPFtQo8neADFb9E9mEjQGxNsteNhJKDCWBBDCwFZZZpI7cCJO3Rl/h6nTJDzgGBgJxojccaTzgW977wCQuxhPoUXlGV0iELqXlU1v4UcKy29udY@n@BT5CfR5V/1srOOweyzDDc2utUyGBlGkQvl/iSv0uIwaTGBgxxuuVsDaL0S/sVRWgHJT6z6Tm@qNsgynIVA442Hz9xAnKG1skXqjEEw1RTtNXWO2SRSnBAGzEoMOmdHXAAomBmBRcFGfMtKRtBGBMUWSoE9Cjo5HaiFlWlDr8abJDcacFzDGJiIAPHx4kipIskmwPmd@J82E5i03vLuJXBDhNWK@1BSFcAW7ImqNYUg6ZJm7HSIjB@HDIb2O4nPKa4uoTJnu@Vvpmo/mmuxmWdFVvSS/JM9ZgVlh2wy6bPxgQt/XznUyl6H@j3qciRYRobYUFlGtiWYjDDfoF9yfAK/dn1GImQhrAPUOR1d4bV5VM89RYAsy57PJVfh17NxjCP0v54VybeXs@PoJEMvez03Uez2WIrT9JLh@bDOn8pO2OxhFECsomuvIrwDb5gvq8rtavUQeSPLejiT36ETTeVvKOUpHdiW7LnqNo9APsGPshu@3DJm4lfqiGFiNTssdOMWOjTNv3VMXvC@c9Kb1ZE8UjKEVdK1DgMkdWcwW@Jl4FJvFm3n37wJPf2zdNW8ng@91M25Dhu@Th6lqS2Ou9ljlh1OpJEt6qe9S6o@b0XJnVy9XLvBxOSxWuft5Uw@/eWimdhQB0@TyLwX2h@Ehwgk10I90C7RDdbALQ1S@ZfqRt8WXc8SfMPSE5u7YorfFMAUAPbwfcEogBPcDnyY@d8o34k03DzDLoNpwDt9IyO1a6WkGL50GPnCuGPRsD16ZtxFc/9q3EVi5hk2bC@iFd6svQh2eMP2ghvRIhMS54NIERqUcDVaFq6@R6MYWLd8cr4ZeMo@c1vJld2g27@1Vj1chsR@N4zij5bbj1pxpjiRILH9yg2nwhKTT8V57I8OfPATE9fzHk92U3xSlMbFvRkJHE3vdGzsD58yadNgVXFvPxwQj1XHgRn0P6c6Co8PkGMk6QfFZariZOVzwk4yiT/Ng2uNCGs40MrWNeiOQcFA3A5LsvYj40eODnGU47mQ2kkv@CTVeOwBRxhXXNMy/haCzxXU5ZPT01Iyk2eUTcpG7frZhunGexfwLp/I5iZoWCmv/rsGHpisQYqbThd0nsaJ31ocfN6BaxtVv7WbjtvZTymb@WhUZN8DXynP0yysHhdSIR7eTG/jzew2bbg@tAM6fJrEAY6pz4COGnMkZv8/jFLmDraB2F/n2lpj5zjAwldumWknkLrN4BqwYEzj/0TclzxFB8PMxCkRB61XE7l7/bwUPt48I1XQTP7Og/jrfnSCC6H@uYo//wU)